# Plot multiple mplfinance plots sharing x axis

Tags: matplotlib, subplot, mplfinance

I am trying to plot 5 charts one under the other with `mplfinance`.

This works:

```
for coin in coins:
    mpf.plot(df_coins[coin], title=coin, type='line', volume=True, show_nontrading=True)
```

However each plot is a separate image in my Python Notebook cell output. And the x-axis labelling is repeated for each image.

I try to make a single figure containing multiple subplot/axis, and plot one chart into each axis:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

N = len(df_coins)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(N, figsize=(20, 5*N), sharex=True)

for i, ((coin, df), ax) in zip(enumerate(df_coins.items()), axes):
    mpf.plot(df, ax=ax, title=coin, type='line', volume=True, show_nontrading=True)
```

This displays subfigures of the correct dimensions, however they are not getting populated with data.  Axes are labelled from 0.0 to 1.0 and the title is not appearing.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to subplot. One is to set up a figure with mplfinance objects. The other way is to use your adopted matplotlib subplot to place it.

**yfinace data**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mplfinance as mpf
import yfinance as yf

tickers = ['AAPL','GOOG','TSLA']
data = yf.download(tickers, start="2021-01-01", end="2021-03-01", group_by='ticker')

aapl = data[('AAPL',)]
goog = data[('GOOG',)]
tsla = data[('TSLA',)]
```

**mplfinance**

```
fig = mpf.figure(style='yahoo', figsize=(12,9))
#fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.3)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(3,1,1, sharex=ax3)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(3,1,2, sharex=ax3)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(3,1,3)

mpf.plot(aapl, type='line', ax=ax1, axtitle='AAPL', xrotation=0)
mpf.plot(goog, type='line', ax=ax2, axtitle='GOOG', xrotation=0)
mpf.plot(tsla, type='line', ax=ax3, axtitle='TSLA', xrotation=0)
ax1.set_xticklabels([])
ax2.set_xticklabels([])
```

**matplotlib**

```
N = len(tickers)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(N, figsize=(20, 5*N), sharex=True)

for df,t,ax in zip([aapl,goog,tsla], tickers, axes):
    mpf.plot(df, ax=ax, axtitle=t, type='line', show_nontrading=True)# volume=True
```

Comment: The volume subplot is not supported, so it is removed from the settings. Please refer to the example in the [official reference](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/external_axes.ipynb). I don't know the name of the virtual currency, so I used the stock data.

Comment: It's ***not*** that the volume subplot is not support.  It **is** that when you are in ***external axes mode*** then mplfinance does *not* know where to put the volume ***unless you tell it***.  Therefore instead of `volume=True` ***you must write*** **`volume=vaxes`** where `vaxes` is the axes that you created where you want the volume to be!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the techniques mentioned by @r-beginners there is another technique that may work for you *in the case where all plots share the same x-axis*.  That is to use `mpf.make_addplot()`.

```py
aps = []
for coin in coins[1:]:
    aps.append(mpf.make_addplot(df_coins[coin]['Close'], title=coin, type='line'))

coin = coins[0]
mpf.plot(df_coins[coin],axtitle=coin,type='line',volume=True,show_nontrading=True,addplot=aps)
```

---

If you choose to do `type='candle'` instead of `'line'`, then change

```py
df_coins[coin]['Close']
```

to simply

```py
df_coins[coin]
```

Comment: My first attempt was to use `make_add_plot()`, but I couldn't do it with an error that a data frame was required. I see that the base graph needs a data frame containing the ohlc values. I have learned.

Comment: @r-beginners  yes, `mpf.plot()` always requires an OHLC DataFrame (or OHLCV).  Whereas `mpf.make_addplot()` accepts a list, array, or series.  The one exception is *if, in the call to* `make_addplot()`, `type='candle'` or `type='ohlc'`, then `make_addplot()` will also demand an OHLC DataFrame.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I understand mpf better again.